# Defining the same variable twice / help understanding

Tags: python

I made this simple Pyglatin translator in a Codeacademy learning exercise. Code is working fine, but need help understanding why.

The variable new_word is defined twice in the if statement. How does the code know to print the second definition of new_word instead of the first. Seems like it would make more sense for the final two lines of the if statement to read like-

```
final_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
print final_word
```

Full working code below-

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
  word = original.lower()
  first = word[0]
  new_word = word + first + pyg
  new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
  print new_word
else:
    print 'empty'
```

Can you keep redefining the same variable and it will always take the last definition given?

Comment: @schwobaseggl It's not pointless at all.

Comment: @schwobaseggl variables exist in functional programming too, where you can NOT reassign them, so that's definitly not "why they are called 'variables'". The term "variable" comes from mathematics FWIW.

Comment: @deceze You are, of course, absolutely right. I didn't pay attention to the rhs of the second `new_word` assignment.

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why a beginner wants to learn Python 2 instead of Python 3?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Well, that may be. But otherwise the term *variable* is frequently used to contrast with *constant*.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I assume you mean "symbolic constants" ? The general definition of a "variable" is that it's a named placeholder for a value which is not yet known, and whose effective value is actually irrelevant (as long as it's in the expected domain) for the algorithm / equation / formula definition. By contrast a "constant" is a value (wether named - like 'Pi' - or litteral - like '42') which is known at definition time and whose value is important. The the definition of the circle's circumference is "2 * Pi * r²", where "2" and "Pi" are constants and "r" is a variable.

Comment: @Piinthesky I didn't even realize I was doing one over the other. I am a total noob. Would I simply change my print statement to print('new_word') in order to be inline with Python 3?

Comment: Well, there is a [whole lot of differences](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/python-2-vs-python-3). But apart from "I like one better than the other", there is one good reason, why [beginners shouldn't start with Python 2](https://pythonclock.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how [imperative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) works. It says *set the value of `new_word` to X. Then set the value of `new_word` to Y.* Each statement does a particular thing, and the statements are followed one by one, modifying the program's state one by one.

You can contrast that with something like [declarative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) in which you only define everything once, and the computer figures out in which order it needs to execute what in order to arrive at the result you described.

Answer (score 1):

In this line you assign the concatenation of `word`, `first` and `pyg` to `new_word`:

```
  new_word = word + first + pyg
```

After that, in this line, you chop off the first char:

```
  new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
```

You indeed use the same var `new_word` twice,
and the newest value (first char chopped off) overwrites the first one (first char still present).

B.T.W. the second line is needlessly complicated, it could also have been:

```
  new_word = new_word[1:]
```

Maybe it helps to realize that a program variable isn't a mathematical variable, and the = in your program isn't a mathematical =.

`a = 3` isn't a proposition meaning that a is equal to 3.
It is an action that puts the number 3 into a memory location labeled a.
So you can always put something else there.

Early languages used := (becomes) instead of = (is), and some languages still use <- to denote this assignment action.

Comment: "a = 3 (...) is an action that puts the number 3 into a memory location labeled a" : well actually that's not how Python works. In Python, `a = 3` creates an `int()` instance (it's memory location being irrelevant) with value 3 and binds this object to name `a` in the current namespace.

Comment: I know, still thanks... just tried to convey a conceptual understanding

Comment: What's the point of "conveying" a _wrong_ "conceptual understanding" ? Explaining Python variables to C programmers (well, to people who's been taught that "a variable is a label for a memory location") again and again is already boring enough.  You could have explained the same thing in a way that is at least as "understandable" while "conceptually correct" for both C-type variables and Python-type variables like: "it is an action that associates the symbolic name 'a' to the numeric value '3' ". No need to talk about memory locations here.

Comment: "it is an action that associates the symbolic name 'a' to the numeric value '3'" is a bit too abstract for a first enounter with the concept of a variable. Most people are aware that data resides somewhere in RAM memory. So I prefer the simplified metaphore, since one can actually imagine something concrete with it. Main point is that OP understands such a link between a name and a value can be changed.